# Deleting all but the max of a row is inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a code that deletes cells that do not contain the max of that given row.

This code would be used in files with a similar layout, just different data.

It worked the first time. However, when I try it in other files with the same conditions and different data, the code sometimes deletes entire rows, even if there is an evident max. The deleted rows are random across files.

I tried a less complicated condition by setting the rule to bold the max instead of deleting. However, the problem repeats (it does not highlight the max of some rows. The same ones that were not deleted before). This leads me to believe that the problem is with either the max itself or something in the cells.

```
Sub deletenonmax()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim max As Integer

Set rng = Range("$E$10:" & Range("E10").End(xlToRight).Address) '<-- first of my rows
Do While rng(1) <> "" '<-- If excel does not detect a blank cell on the first position
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(rng) '<-- This is how I get the max of current row
    For Each cell In rng '<-- loop through the cells of the row
        If cell.Value <> max Then '<-- if the value of the cell is not the max
            cell.Value = "" '<-- set it to empty
        End If
    Next cell
    Set rng = Range(rng(1).Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & rng(1).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Address) '<-- Go to the line below
    rng.Select
Loop
End Sub
```

In some cases it deletes everything BUT the max values of the row.

In some cases the entire row ends up empty.

Comment: Are some of the max values too large for integer type or are decimals?

Comment: Also, you don't need `rng.Select`

Comment: To add to the commentors above, you should qualify all of your ranges correctly.

Comment: change `Set rng = Range("$E$10:" & Range("E10").End(xlToRight).Address)` to `Set rng = Range("E10", Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest trying code like this instead (modified as needed):

```
Option Explicit
Sub deleteMax()
Dim r As Range, cell As Range, sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set r = sh.Range("E10")
While r(1) <> ""
    Set r = sh.Range(r, r.End(xlToRight))
    For Each cell In r
        'cell.Select
        If cell <> Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r) Then cell.Font.Color = vbRed
    Next cell
    Set r = r(1).Offset(1, 0)
Wend
End Sub
```

It worked for me for both integers and real numbers, as shown below in 2 examples I tried. I just colored them red, but of course, you would want to delete them using cell = ""

[image]

[image]

If there is a set of data that doesn't work with this code, let me know.

Comment: This did the trick :) Thanks a lot for helping me. I am new to this and trying my best!!

Comment: I'm happy you were helped. As I said, this was just code to get you started and should be "modified as needed".  For example, I assumed all rows were of the same length. So, I altered  slightly so that it can handle rows of different lengths